# What are Vert.x EventBus messages ordering guarantees?

Tags: java, vert.x, vertx-verticle, vertx-eventbus

[Documention says](https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/java/#_message_ordering):

> Vert.x will deliver messages to any particular handler in the same order they were sent from any particular sender.

What is meant by a handler or sender: verticle, context, particular callback or something else?

Will all messages from sender verticle to subscription verticle be delivered in the same order no matter how many addresses were used for communication?

Answer (score 0):

> Vert.x will deliver messages to any particular handler in the same order they were sent from any particular sender.

This is more than clear. If you send A,B,C then vertx will send them out in that order since it is purely passing it forward.

> What is meant by a handler or sender: verticle, context, particular callback or something else?

Handler is the receiver which will get the message. Sender is the sender who is sending the message.

If the sender sent A, B, C then the handler will receive the messages in the same order  i.e. A,B, C - since vertx is purely forwarding the message

> Will all messages from sender verticle to subscription verticle be delivered in the same order no matter how many addresses were used for communication?

Yes - but do not misunderstand this as that ordering will be maintained across addresses - in the scope of a single address the messages will be in the same order